# How do i set php executable path in php using in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, json

I have developed a website in Visual Studio Code with a contact form, I am currently learning PHP.

I get a message on the screen that takes me to settings.json to validate the executable path but do not know what to enter between the 2 "".

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "php.validate.executablePath": ""
}
```

Comment: This completely depends on your particular installation of your particular OS. You'll generally want the full path to the php binary, which (on a unix-y OS) can be had via `type php`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "c:/xampp/php/php.exe" 
}
```

Depends on your installation directory